# What will happen if we compile a Oracle package with different name?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, package, procedure

I have a sql package that contains many stored procedures.

```
create or replace package body My_Pck is
    /** Package started **/

    /** Procedure 1 **/
    procedure one() as
    begin
    end;

    /** Procedure 2 **/
    procedure one() as
    begin
    end;
My_Pck end;
```

The question is if I compile this package with different name what will happen? The other procedures that are in the new package will override the original procedure? I searched a lot but din't get the suitable ans.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: If you compile a package with a diffirent name, then you will get 2 packages. Why do you want to compele the package with an other name? If the first name is not well choosen and the second is well choosen then you can drop the first package.

Comment: packages support encapsulation - all procedures inside package belongs to the package... different packages can have procedures with the same names - but this will be different procedures...

Comment: no. the first package is used in application. and i made some modification to the package. So for testing purpose i need to compile the package with another name.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to understand a point.

Package is basically collection of procedures, functions , etc. The procedures which are defined inside a package, can not be called independent without specifying qualifier package name. These procedures are always used as package.procedure.

lets consider your package. You can call the procedure  like My_Pck.one.

```
create or replace package body My_Pck is
/** Package started **/

/** Procedure 1 **/
procedure one() as
begin
end;

/** Procedure 2 **/
procedure one() as
begin
end;
My_Pck end;
```

if you compile package with different name like below, then you need to call procedure as my_pck2.one.

```
create or replace package body My_Pck2 is
/** Package started **/

/** Procedure 1 **/
procedure one() as
begin
end;

/** Procedure 2 **/
procedure one() as
begin
end;
My_Pck end;
```

Thanks